# React uncaught error fail to get ".page__content" element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was developing in react, and all of the sudden, I get `fail to get ".page__content" element.`.

Googling yielded nothing.

Happened after I added `<Text>Or:</Text>`.

Using React `15.0.2`.

What the error means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, I hope one of the ReactJS developers can explain why, this error message happens when you use a built-in React Native component that doesn't exist (since we're not using react native here).

If you forget to use the **capital letter**, effectively using a non existing component `<asdf>Or:</asdf>` nothing happens (weird! no error message?!).

I checked with another built-in component `<Image>Or:</Image>`, it generated the same error message.

Also, a tip, if you're using a UI framework that supports react, be very careful of components, if, for example, one uses Onsen UI, and does `<Page>Or:</Page>`, the Page component takes over the whole page, so be careful with components!